# How to convert a selection to lowercase or uppercase in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext

I have several strings selected in a file in Sublime Text and I want to convert them all to lowercase.

How can I convert them all to lowercase in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 850, accepted):

From the [Sublime Text docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html#text-manipulation) for Windows/Linux:

```
Keypress            Command
Ctrl + K, Ctrl + U  Transform to Uppercase
Ctrl + K, Ctrl + L  Transform to Lowercase
```

and [for Mac](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html#text-manipulation):

```
Keypress    Command
cmd + KU    Transform to Uppercase
cmd + KL    Transform to Lowercase
```

Also note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> in Windows (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> in a Mac) brings up the [Command Palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html) where you can search for these and other commands. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm used to Notepad++ where you can just select text and use right mouse button to manipulate it. Sublime lacks a lot of mouse manipulations

Comment: I wonder why I always learn such things from SO instead of a documentation :)

Comment: Too Bad There Isn't Sentence & Title Case Shortcuts, That'd be Something.

Comment: @BenRacicot No problem, add the built-in functions to your key bindings (Preferences -> Key Bindings-User):
    `[
      { "keys": ["super+k", "super+t"], "command": "title_case" },
    ]`

Comment: It's actually Ctrl + KU and Ctrl + KL for Windows too. At least in ST2 which is the one I'm using.

Comment: Is there something to have Title Form (See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized or http://titlecase.com/ or http://titlecapitalization.com/)?

Comment: Just to help memorize it: in emacs it is `Ctrl`+`x`, `Ctrl`+`u/l`.

Comment: I wish there was a `Toggle Case` command. Changing case is done so rarely that it would be convenient to have it under just one action key instead of two. Like, if there is at least one uppercase character in selection, it goes all uppercased. If not, all goes lowercase. I would prefer to press it twice to make it lowercase instead of having a separate key.

Answer (score 82):

For Windows:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for UPPERCASE.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for lowercase.

**Method 1** (Two keys pressed at a time)

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hold.
2. Now press <kbd>K</kbd>, release <kbd>K</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. (Do not release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key)
3. Immediately, press <kbd>U</kbd> (for uppercase) OR <kbd>L</kbd> (for lowercase) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> still being pressed, then release all pressed keys.

**Method 2** (3 keys pressed at a time)

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hold.
2. Now press <kbd>K</kbd>.
3. Without releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd>, immediately press <kbd>U</kbd> (for uppercase) OR <kbd>L</kbd> (for lowercase) and release all pressed keys.

Please note: If you press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for more than two seconds it will start deleting text so try to be quick with it.

I use the above shortcuts, and they work on my Windows system.

Comment: the steps explained in this answer made it work for me.

Comment: Works on Sublime Text 3175 @ Ubuntu 18.04 too!

Answer (score 30):

As a bonus for setting up a Title Case shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>kt</kbd> (while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, press <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd>), go to `Preferences` --> `Keybindings-User`

If you have a blank file open and close with the square brackets:

```
[  { "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+t"], "command": "title_case" } ]
```

Otherwise if you already have stuff in there, just make sure if it comes after another command to prepend a comma "," and add:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+t"], "command": "title_case" }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this.

Answer (score 21):

For Windows OS

For Uppercase
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>**

For Lowercase
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>**

Answer (score 7):

For others needing a key binding:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+="], "command": "upper_case" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+-"], "command": "lower_case" }
```