# How to convert from lower to upper case in Sublime 3

Tags: shortcut, uppercase, lowercase, sublimetext3

Is there a shortcut or function for upper/lower-casing the selected text in Sublime 3?

Comment: Even though I am using Sublime Text 3, [this][1] answer still helped me.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773886/how-do-i-convert-strings-to-lowercase-or-uppercase-in-sublime-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert selection to lowercase (or uppercase) in Sublime Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773886/convert-selection-to-lowercase-or-uppercase-in-sublime-text)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

if you need convert any text, select and press:
ctrl + KU

Comment: Ctrl + K + L for lowercasing

Answer (score 11):

If you go to the `Edit` menu and select `Convert Case` you'll find several options, with the appropriate shortcuts listed next to them. Additionally, the [Case Conversion](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Case%20Conversion) plugin, available through Package Control, adds a number of additional options to this menu for converting variables, such as `snake_case`, `camelCase`, `PascalCase`, `dot.case`, and others.

Comment: Case Conversion is great