# Capitalize selection in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, capitalize

Is there a way to capitalize a selection in Sublime? For example, if I have some text like `word`, I'd like the output to be `Word`.

I know that there is already an option to convert case into lower case or upper case, but those would result in `word` and `WORD` respectively. Is there a way to only capitalize the first letter?

Comment: Use menu _Edit>Convert Case>Title Case

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I didn't realize it existed because there was no default key mapping set for the command.

Comment: That happens many times :) You're welcome.

Comment: @sergioFC Post this as an answer so it can be accepted and canonized, get some rep for yourself, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert selection to lowercase (or uppercase) in Sublime Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773886/convert-selection-to-lowercase-or-uppercase-in-sublime-text)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question, doing the uppercase or lowercase command will affect every single letter, not just the first one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it using the **menu *Edit>Convert Case>Title Case***.

In case you want to set a keybinding the name of the associated command is `title_case`.

Answer (score 2):

Add keybinding under the preferences as follows:

```
[
// for uppercase:
  { "keys": ["ctrl+u"], "command": "upper_case" },

// for lowercase:
  { "keys": ["ctrl+l"], "command": "lower_case" },

// for titlecase:
  { "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "title_case" },
]
```

Comment: There are already other shortcuts for upper and lower case, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18773887/379841 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18922666/379841