# Select all found RegEx results in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to select all of the results found by a regex find so I can modify them all (*not replace them with text!*), for example, making them all uppercase with `Cmd + K -> Cmd + U`. I'm aware that I *could* do them one by one via repeating `Cmd + G, Cmd + K, Cmd + U`, but for a large file this simply isn't practical or realistic. I'm also aware of using bash and may other scripting alternatives, I'd like to find a way to do it inside Atom, I'm happy to install an external library if needed.

[image: Example of selection]

Things I've tried:

1. `Cmd + D`, this just selects the next instance of that exact letter, not the next result matching the regex.
2. `Cmd + Shift + G` and alternatives (alt/right shift/ctrl), `Cmd + G` selects the next result matching the Regex, which is in the right direction.
3. Changing all of the selected text to a unique string, highlighting them all, pressing `Cmd + Z` and hoping it will stay selected, it doesn't.
4. Lots of Googling and reading though [Atom discussions](https://discuss.atom.io/t/multiple-selections/755/2).
5. Reading [Atom's documentation on the subject](https://atom.io/docs/v0.194.0/using-atom-find-and-replace)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Pressing `Alt + Enter` will select all instances matching your Find results. This works for RegEx search also.

Source: https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/pull/290

Comment: @MikaA. it's still Alt-Enter.

Comment: @MikaA. [alt] translates to [option] on Macs.  Most keyboards include both words on the same key.

Comment: This is really neat for some things that are hard or impossible with Atom's regex replace (e.g. converting to lowercase), but it only applies to one file at a time. I could imagine an improved regex replace that does most of this on multiple files at once.

Comment: On Atom 1.57 (nov 2021) you click "find all" then copy :)

Answer (score 4):

On Atom 1.57 (nov 2021) clicking on "find all" selects all matching items, esc to exit the search box, then copy :)

[image]

Alternatively you can select all whit the menu -> find > select all.

On mac also selects all by pressing `^ + cmd + G`.

Comment: thank you @NicoKowe, you saved my life. I did this - clicking on "find all" selects all matching items, esc to exit the search box, then copy :)