# regex uppercase replacement not working on atom

Tags: regex, replace, find, atom-editor

I want to target lowercases after a . and convert it to uppercase. It seems like Atom is not understanding /U /E ?
This is what I have

```
(\. \n{0,})([a-z])
```

and replace with

```
$1\U$2\E
```

Input: level. the mu-law is 
Output: level. \Ut\Ehe mu-law is 
Expected: level. The mu-law is 
I have regex enabled and case match enabled. Is this an atom issue?

Comment: Just Atom regex engine does not support case changing operators. If you need this feature use Notepad++.

Comment: thanks ill put my work around for now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So as Wiktor says, atom doesnt support \U \L...
work around as stated in [another regex atom thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673382/atom-editor-regex-replace-to-uppercase-lowercase)

use:

```
(\. \n{0,})([a-z])
```

hit find all and mannual click:

```
Edit --> Text --> Upper
```

--and if all of them dont turn upper, mess around with replace, undo, the blinking cursor should be on all the texts, now do the manual clicks

Comment: I believe that's the first time I saw an answer with negative votes and marked as correct. It made me think...